# Critical points theorem for regular surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $f:U \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function defined on an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $a \in f(U)$.

If the set $f^{-1}(a)=S$ doesn't have any critical points of $f$ then it is a regular surface.

The critical points $(x,y,z)$ are the points that $ \nabla f (x,y,z)=0$.

**My question is:** Is the opposite statement true, specifically:

Is it true that if $f^{-1}(a)=S$ is a regular surface, then it doesn't contain any critical points of $f$?

Comment: You mean to ask whether if $f^{-1}(a)$ is regular then it doesn't contain any critical points of $f$?

Comment: Yes, this is what i mean

Comment: You need major proofreading.

Answer (score 5):

No; it is possible for a fiber to be regular "by accident" even if it contains critical points.  For instance, consider the function $f(x,y,z)=(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)^2$.  Then every point of $f^{-1}(0)$ is critical, but $f^{-1}(1)$ is a regular surface (the unit sphere).